# How to sort by Tier PL SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| John | 111 |
| Jack | 115 |
| Joe | 120 |
| Jimmuy | 125 |
| Jill | 135 |

I need to sort them in new column in tiers like range in:

- below 113
- From 113 to 120
- from 121 to 130
- from 131

and the output should look like this

| Name | Score | Tier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 111 | 1 |
| Jack | 115 | 2 |
| Joe | 120 | 2 |
| Jimmuy | 125 | 3 |
| Jill | 135 | 4 |

Comment: What do you mean by *sort in new column* and where do those ranges come from? Please edit your question accordingly and add your expected output into it (and your current code also)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to apply a score to a particular range. If you really want to then you can `ORDER` by those ranges (or a priority based on those ranges):

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE
       WHEN score <  113 THEN 1
       WHEN score <  121 THEN 2
       WHEN score <  131 THEN 3
       WHEN score >= 131 THEN 4
       END AS tier
FROM   table_name t
ORDER BY tier;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Name, Score) AS
SELECT 'John',   111 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jack',   115 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Joe',    120 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jimmuy', 125 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jill',   135 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NAME | SCORE | TIER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 111 | 1 |
| Jack | 115 | 2 |
| Joe | 120 | 2 |
| Jimmuy | 125 | 3 |
| Jill | 135 | 4 |

However, you could just use `ORDER BY score` rather than `ORDER BY tier`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ExMV8yKr)